# Catching File Exceptions using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

The below is what I am wrestling with today using Visual Studios Console App.

What I want to happen, which currently isn't, is when the Console App opens, and I type the first "checksPath" in, if this turns out to not exist, I want it to say that the path is wrong, and either, let the user try again, or close the app. If the path is valid, then it moves onto the next "reportDest", and the same applies. If it's an invalid path, I want a message saying so, with the option of trying again, or closing the app. If both paths entered (eventually) are valid, I want a message to say that the report will now produce. The rest of the script that produces the report is perfectly fine, it's just the bit i've put below that's troublesome.

```
            string checksPath;
        Console.Write("Please enter the source path for the Checks Workbook, including the name of the file (Not including the file extension): ");
        checksPath = Console.ReadLine() + ".xlsx";

        try
        {
            if (File.Exists("checksPath"))
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid path - Please close the app and try again!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }



            string reportDest;
            Console.Write("Please enter the folder location and file you wish your report to go to (Not including the file extension): ");
            reportDest = Console.ReadLine() + ".xlsx";

        try
        {
            if (File.Exists("reportDest"))
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid path - Please close the app and try again!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }



        Console.WriteLine("Your report will now produce");
```

Comment: Exception handing is for *exceptional* situations. In this case, you *should* use `if`/`else` to handle *expected* conditions.

Comment: How about  `if (!File.Exists("checksPath"))`

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to continually ask a question until the user gets it right, you will need a loop. Next in that loop you need to check if the path exists.

```
            bool run = true;

            while (run)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Path:");
                string answer = Console.ReadLine();

                if (Directory.Exists(answer)) run = false;
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Path Does not exists. Try again. Press enter to continue...");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
```